# How to pivot a large dataset for recommender system with panda?

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I am doing a recommender system with 300,000 users and 280,000 items, people usually doing recommender system by pivoting the dataframe into a table:

`df.pivot_table(index='User-ID',columns='Item-ID',values='Rating')`

But it's impossible to pivot such a huge dataset into a table. What is a common way to deal with this problem? Or people use other structures to do the recommender system?

Comment: Put them into index , like df = df.set_index(['User-ID','Item-ID'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is definitely a better way to save a huge amount of computations and memory. The matrix we create of user-item is usually sparse and contains a large number of zeros, which tremendously increases the computations and memory complexity. 
For example:

```
        Per1    Per2    Per3    Per4    Per5    Per6    Per7    per8
Item1    5        0        1     0       0        0       0       0    
Ttem2    0        3        0     0       2        0       0       0
```

Here zeros in the matrix increase computations.

A much better way to store the matrix is to store the matrix with a **compressed sparse row matrix algorithm**. It removes all the zero value and stores only the non-zero values.Here is the easy function to create a csr matrix for recommendation system:-

```
def create_matrix(data, user_col, item_col, rating_col):
    """
    creates the sparse user-item interaction matrix

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : DataFrame
        implicit rating data

    user_col : str
        user column name

    item_col : str
        item column name

    ratings_col : str
        implicit rating column name
    """



    # create a sparse matrix of using the (rating, (rows, cols)) format
    rows = data[user_col].cat.codes
    cols = data[item_col].cat.codes
    rating = data[rating_col]
    ratings = csr_matrix((rating, (rows, cols)))
    ratings.eliminate_zeros()
    return ratings, data
```

I hope it will be helpfull!!!